# SQL Query to fetch defects which is linked to Test Set , Test Case and Test Step from ALM

Tags: alm

I am using below query but it is not extracting defects which is linked to Test Steps of Test Cases.
So all the defects which are linked to test steps are not coming out.

```
SELECT Distinct BUG.BG_BUG_ID as "Defect ID", BUG.BG_DETECTED_BY as "Detected By", BUG.BG_SUMMARY as "Defect Name", BUG.BG_USER_03 as "Application", BUG.BG_USER_01 as "Category", LINK.LN_ENTITY_TYPE as "Type", TEST.TS_TEST_ID as "Test ID", TEST.TS_NAME as "Test Name", TEST.TS_USER_03 as "Test Category"
FROM LINK, BUG, TEST,STEP Where LINK.LN_BUG_ID = BUG.BG_BUG_ID AND LINK.LN_ENTITY_ID = TS_TEST_ID --AND BUG.BG_STATUS in ('Closed', 'Canceled', 'Duplicate') AND BUG.BG_DETECTED_IN_RCYC in (Select RELEASE_CYCLES.RCYC_ID from RELEASE_CYCLES where RELEASE_CYCLES.RCYC_NAME IN ('UAT - 3.1 MVA'))

Order by BUG.BG_BUG_ID
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What does your table look like? What results are you expecting from the query? Can you simplify the query for testing and build it up little by little?

Comment: Query to fetch defects which is linked to Test Set , Test Case and Test Step from HP ALM (HPQC) by query bulider